# How can I setup pi-hole next together with another website securely on the same raspberry?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm hosting a nextcloud instance, accessible via a free subdomain, on my raspberry pi.
For this purpose I run an apache server on my rasperry and I forwarded port 443 on my router.

Now I've also installed pi-hole on it, but I found that the dashboard is accessible via my public IP address due to the port-forward.

How can I configure my raspberry pi such that:

- the nextcloud instance remains accessible from the web
- the pi-hole dashboard is only accessible from the local network

### What I've tried

As the lighttpd service was installed during the pi-hole setup I thought shutting it down would disable the web interface. Unfortunately stopping the lighttpd service didn't change anything
I suspect the dashboard remains visible due to the apache webserver.

Comment: `I suspect the dashboard remains visible due to the apache webserver` .. why don't you make sure that is true

Comment: Ah, always great to have a warm welcome to the community :) I'll see if stopping the apache server disables access to the pi-hole admin page. However, I want to keep the apache server running (for nextcloud), so how can I do that?

Comment: i am not  very familiar with apache ... there should be logs that you could check ... maybe you don't have to shut it down